# Trouble plotting Mysql data to Google Charts using PHP, AJAX, JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I'm having trouble getting a Google Charts Line chart to generate.  I've been perusing the web and stackexchange for examples.

Right now I'm logging temperature data from my nest and I'd like to plot it along with some other data.

This is my getdata_line.php mysql query with ajax:

```
<?php
/* $server = the IP address or network name of the server
 * $userName = the user to log into the database with
 * $password = the database account password
 * $databaseName = the name of the database to pull data from
 */

$con = mysqli_connect('192.168.146.1', 'TestUser', 'testuser1','nest') or die('Error connecting to server');


// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)
$query = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM nest_log WHERE time_stamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ORDER by time_stamp ASC');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
    //array('label' => 'time_stamp', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'index', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'current_temperature', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    //$temp[] = array('v' => $r['time_stamp']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['index']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['current_temperature']); // typecast all numbers to the appropriate type (int or float) as needed - otherwise they are input as strings

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

This is the line.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLine);

            function drawLine() {
                var json = $.ajax({
                    url: 'getdata_line.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                var options = {
                    //title: 'My Weekly Plan',
                    //is3D: 'true',
                    //width: 800,
                    //height: 600
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

                chart.draw(data, options);

            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="line_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

getdata_line.php is returning:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"index","type":"number"},{"label":"current_temperature","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"625"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"626"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"627"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"628"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"629"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"630"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"631"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"632"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"633"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"634"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"635"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"636"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"637"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"638"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"639"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"640"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"641"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"642"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"643"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"644"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"645"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"646"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"647"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"648"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"649"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"650"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"651"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"652"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"653"},{"v":70.591982}]},{"c":[{"v":"654"},{"v":70.591982}]}]}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: no error, just chart generated